# importing system in python - import packages

Tags: python, import, module

When I have the following packages:

```
src
   /__main__.py
   /dir1
        /__init__.py
        /main_code1.py
        /service.py
        /config.py
   /dir2
       /__init__.py
       /maincode2.py
   /dir3
       /__init__.py
       /maincode3.py
```

What is the difference between using the following statement in the file `__main__.py`

```
import dir1
```

&

```
from dir1 import *
```

&

```
from dir1 import main_code1
```

The second question is: How to import maincode3.py (present in dir3) to the maincode.py script present in dir1? I am searching for way without changing sys.path list.

Answer (score 2):

```
import dir1
```

Imports dir1's `__init__.py`. You can access whatever is there using `dir1.my_var_from_dir1_init`. You cannot access the modules, only what's on dir1's `__init__`.

```
from dir1 import *
```

Imports the modules specified on the `__all__` variable defined on dir1's `__init__.py`. If there isn't such variable, then it imports all of dir1's modules. You can access them directly, like `main_code1.myvar`.

```
from dir1 import maincode
```

Assuming it's a typo and you actually have a `maincode` module or class, it imports the `maincode` module/class from dir1. You can access it directly like mentioned above.

Note that each option imports dir1's `__init__.py`, implicitly or explicitly. If you import the modules on `__init__.py`, then using `import dir1` will allow you to use `dir1.module`.

---

To import dir3's `maincode3` to `maincode.py`, simply use `from dir3 import maincode3`. Just be careful with circular imports, which will generate an import error. You can also take a look on [relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python).

Comment: when I use (from dir1 import maincode1) and the  __init__.py contain line like :(import service , config )  , Is the modules config & service imported or not ??

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself? They are imported, but I guess you can't access them directly.

Answer (score 1):

- `import dir1` will import dir1/__init__.py file.
- `from dir1 import *`: all modules inside dir1 will be imported. Access "main_code1" without using the "dir." before.
- `from dir1 import main_code1` will only import the main_code1 module.

If the __main__.py file is importing all the other modules, then you can access dir3.maincode3.py from dir1.main_code1.py simply doing something like:

`import dir3.maincode3`